# PhpStorm - Highlight active file in project navigator

Tags: phpstorm

Does anyone know how to highlight the current file in the project navigator, or a hotkey to expand folders to the active file?

I have looked around and couldn't find anything that points to this as an option.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Here is a nice feature: `Autoscroll to Source` and `Autoscroll from Source`.

It is available in all IntelliJ products .

[image: Autoscroll to Source, Autoscroll from Source]

Comment: This highlights the file, but it doesn't select it, so any more keyboard activity will still be registered in the editor window.

Comment: In case u got here by googling and wonder if it still the same for your version: **this is the same for 2017**

Comment: 2017 also has a crosshairs Icon up there when autoscroll is turned off. so you can click that and it will jump to source.

Comment: autoscroll from source is what I needed. when I use the quick search (using shift+shift) it'll scroll to the file in the source. very useful thanks.

Comment: @Artistan where is the crosshairs icon?

Comment: Found it! The crosshair icon is in between the 'Project' dropdown and the minimize/settings cog icon.  It did not appear as the auto scroll options were still turned on.

Answer (score 191):

### On Demand

*Should be used if you do not like when your Project View panel gets changed/moves without your consent.*

`Navigate | Select in... | Project View`

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> for Windows/Linux

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd> (or <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>) for Mac OS

---

You may also click on "target like" icon on actual Project View panel with your mouse:

[image]

---

If you wish to use shorter/single shortcut instead of standard 2-step shortcut:

- install **"Extra Actions" plugin**
- assign custom shortcut to newly provided "Select in Project" action

**As of some 2017.x version** (or maybe even 2016.x) the IDE has own dedicated `Select in Project View` action (so no need for additional plugin). You can find it in `Keymap` under the `Other` branch (hint: use search box to narrow the list).

---

### Automatically

Can be used if you do not mind (or even want) to have Project View panel keep focused on currently edited file (so it scrolls/moves up and down/expands when needed).

*NOTE: with frequently switching between the files (e.g. CSS & HTML) when you have a lot of files in your project such "scrolling" may become quite annoying pretty fast (especially if such files are located in the invisible-right-now part of the project tree).*

Activate `Autoscroll from Source` option in Project View panel (right click on tool window header bar/title or use menu under "gear" icon):

[image]

**In modern versions (2020.3 and newer)** that option was renamed and is now called `Always Select Opened File`:

[image]
[image: 2003 design]

Comment: It seems that in newer versions, `Autoscroll from Source` has been renamed to `Always select opened file` and has been moved further down in the menu.

Comment: Sorry but I dont see this shortcut working in Ubuntu (20) + PhpStorm (2022)

Comment: @Jono Your Linux / desktop manager may use the shortcut for own needs. 1) Check your OS / desktop settings; 2) Does the action work if you invoke the actual menu item via Main Menu? 3) What is the shortcut shown there? Maybe it's different in your Keymap. 4) If it's `Alt + F1` and it works when calling the menu item manually (with the mouse) -- go to `Settings | Keymap` -- there is a button next to the local search field. Use it and see if the IDE will recognize the shortcut. If it does not, then something intercepts it.

Answer (score 16):

Just click the circular icon (with tooltip **Scroll from Source**) to navigate in the **project directory tree** and highlight the corresponding active file in the PhpStorm editor.

[image: Screenshot - Scroll from Source]

Answer (score 16):

On PhpStorm 2020.3 you have to click the **cog icon** in the **project pane** and select ***Always Select Opened Files***:

[image: screenshot]

[image: 2023 redesign looks]

Comment: Can confirm that this works on PHP/WebStorm versions that came out in 2023.

Answer (score 5):

The above answers are all valid but unfortunately you'll have to enable them for each project.

There's a plugin from Jetbrains that will enable this behaviour by default for all new projects.

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7575?pr=