# In WebStorm, how can someone view the current file in the Project View?

Tags: webstorm

With WebStorm, here is how I find the file containing a specific word. I painfully

- global-search a word,
- click open the file, then
- memorize its path and try to
- click my way down the folder structure.

There must be an easier way!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27281201/783119 -- `Navigate | Select in... | Project View`

Answer (score 1):

Once file is opened/current, locate it in folder structure by **clicking** on the icon, shown (called 'scroll from source')  [image]

enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There is a **Scroll from source** button in the **Project view** toolbar

[image]

it selects the currently opened file in the project tree. Also, you can assign a preferred shortcut to **Select in Project View** action in `Settings | Keymap | Other`.
Another option is using `Navigate | Select in... | Project View`.

Note that you can enable auto-scrolling from source for all files: open **Project View** options dropdown and choose the **Autoscroll from source** - when it's enabled, current file is auto-selected in the Project view on opening.